# Computer shut off randomly - no overheating

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, ssd, power-supply, shutdown

This is the first time this has happened. I started my computer, and 40-50 mins in, it shut off. No screen, no lights, nothing. I believe the ssd or vents still made some sound though (yes, my ssd for some reason makes a sound, specially when scrolling). I checked temp, my computer was as cool as it gets.

I started it up again, and it booted up as normal, no problem.

I have event log ID 41 `KERNEL-POWER`- (`The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.`) and `EVENT LOG 6008` - (`The previous system shutdown at 2:13:12 AM on ‎8/‎5/‎2015 was unexpected.`) .

I am guessing it was a power failure. However my computer was plugged-in (and power still on) and with battery on. Could it be the Power Supply Unit?

I am running a Dell Inspiron 15 7548, Windows 8.1, Samsung SSD 850 Evo (256GB), AMD Radeon R7 M270. At the moment of shutdown only Chrome was opened playing a streaming video on a Flash plugin. Which makes me believe that it could also be the graphics card or controller. However I'm used to watching movies and series for long periods, never happened, and also a little gaming.

Any help appreciated

Thank you very much

Comment: When I encountered this error on my personal PC it was a display driver problem.

Comment: did you update all your drivers? specially graphic card etc?

Comment: What temperatures did you check and what were the readings exactly?

Comment: @fixer1234: It's a laptop. Laptops have batteries.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my desktop PC. Turned out that the graphics card was pulling too much power in "spikes" from the PSU. So sounds like a hardware problem.